# how to address movie from html (android data folder)

Tags: android, video, webview

I have a webview in android studio that I want to load and play movie in it.
I use this code:

```
String path=Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/newfoldername";
```

for saving the movie file from /raw folder to /data/data... folder and it copied.
I try it for another folder and they worked too.

I use this code in (html) file :

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="/data/data/com.packagename.appname/newfoldername/m0.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

what is the solution to use (dynamic code) insted of (hardcode) in HTML file please?

Comment: You should tell full paths of video and html.

Comment: can you explain more... for example: \datat\data\com.package.appname\newfoldername\m0.mp4 not worked    I don't want to use hardcode in html file... is there any way please?

Comment: I asked for two paths.

Comment: And show more code and explain better as nobody knows what you are doing.

Comment: Briefly, I want to use a maked path in JAVA in a HTML file.         mean: I make a path such as    strpath=Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/newfoldername";          in java file     NOW, I want to use strpath in HTML file.        or any other way to make same strpath value in HTML file.    Hope you explain it well

Comment: Dont understand a word of it. Moreover you should put all in your post. Not in comments. Tell two paths and showrelevant part of your html. All in your post.

Comment: can u check again please... I edit the question... @greenapps

Comment: You did not post two full paths.